# How to get default variation ID (woocommerce)

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, links, variables

I need to create an additional "Add to Cart" button on the product page. In a simple product there is no problem with this. It is more difficult in a product with variants. To create such a button I need to know the ID of the default variant.

```
$product->get_default_attributes();
```

returns only the attribute name and value, no ID.

How to get the ID of the default variant in php code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $selectedPrice = '';
    $dump = '';

    foreach ( $available_variations as $variation )
    {
        // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($variation['attributes'], true) . '</pre>';

        $isDefVariation=false;
        foreach($product->get_default_attributes() as $key=>$val){
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($key, true) . '</pre>';
            // $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($val, true) . '</pre>';
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$key]==$val){
                $isDefVariation=true;
            }   
        }
        if($isDefVariation){
            $price = $variation['display_price'];         
        }
    }
    $selectedPrice = wc_price($price);

//  $dump = $dump . '<pre>' . var_export($available_variations, true) . '</pre>';

    return $selectedPrice . $dump;
}
```